# app.config weirdness

Tags: c#, app-config

I've got a strange thing happening with my app.config file. My ConnectionStrings section contains this:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Connection" connectionString="Data Source=TheServer;
   Initial Catalog=TheDatabase;IntegratedSecurity=SSPI" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

However, when I query the section via ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0], I get back this connection string:

```
Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
```

Where is it getting this value from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is read from machine.config, you can either make sure to clear all connection strings before adding your own:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <clear/>
  <add name="Connection" connectionString="Data Source=TheServer;
   Initial Catalog=TheDatabase;IntegratedSecurity=SSPI" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Or just never reference your connection strings by indexes, use names you give them:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"]
```

Answer (score 1):

It comes from machine.config.  .NET Automatically merges the connection string sections (and some others I believe) of your application config (or web config) and your machine.config.

You can read about how it works in ASP.NET [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx).

Comment: I see. Thank you. Why isn't it referencing the app.config file then? I haven't had this happen before.

Comment: @woodstock: it is, but you are calling it by the index, and 0 happens to be the first one defined up in the hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

It's coming from another config, either a higher up app.config in the tree or the machine config. To ignore anything else use `<clear />` to get rid of anything not in the current config.

```
<connectionStrings>
   <clear />
   <add name="Connection" connectionString="Data Source=TheServer;
     Initial Catalog=TheDatabase;IntegratedSecurity=SSPI" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition to Nath's answer, this is better :

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the question's been answered by Jason Punyon, I'd strongly recommend accessing your connection strings via their name rather than their index.
e.g.

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"]
```